# Is there a way to change behaviour of Alt + L in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

RubyMine version 2017.3.1

Currently when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> while composing commit message within *Commit Changes* window the "Cleanup" checkbox gets toggled.

Is there a way to turn off this context dependent <kbd>ALT</kbd> key behaviour?

It prevents me from typing certain diacritic characters.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance --> Disable mnemonics...` option? Not ideal .. but that's the only way AFAIK (unless you can enter your "certain diacritic characters" in some another way (which possibly will be less convenient).

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you. There might not be an ideal solution but yours made my day. I have unchecked `Disable mnemonics in controls` as to your suggestion and now I can type `ł, ś, ć, ą, ń and ó` in a commit message.